# Appium android driver + js - simple example

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I have to test native android app, with test written in js.
I cannot find working example of this concept.

```
import { AndroidDriver } from "appium-android-driver"
```

This import throw many errors, I am looking for a hint - working simple project.

Answer (score 0):

This way of importing works with latest version of Node JS. Make sure your using the latest version. The other work around is to use the legacy way

```
var AndroidDriver = require('appium-android-driver').AndroidDriver;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That You, that solution help me !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wd.js](https://github.com/admc/wd) as Node.js client for Appium:

Taking in account you are familiar with *async/await* concept, the code may look like:

```
const wd = require('wd')

const serverConfig = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 4723
}
const desired = {
  platformName: 'Android',
  deviceName: 'Android Emulator',
  appWaitActivity: <activity to wait>,
  appWaitPackage: <app package name>,
  androidInstallTimeout: 90000,
  app: <path to app>
}

const driver = wd.promiseChainRemote(serverConfig)

await driver.init(desired)
await driver.setImplicitWaitTimeout(5000)
await driver.elementById('el_id').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to require wd as it is automatically imported from 'nativescript-dev-appium'

It looks like you are using typescript. Here is a typescript solution:

```
import { AppiumDriver, createDriver, SearchOptions, 
         Direction, nsCapabilities } from "nativescript-dev-appium";
import { assert } from "chai";
const addContext = require('mochawesome/addContext');
```

Then in the same file instantiate a driver instance and use that instance:

```
describe('My Suite', () => {
  let driver: AppiumDriver

  before(async () => {
    // Wait for the driver instance to be created
    driver = await createDriver()
  })

  after(async () => {
    // Destroy the driver instance
    await driver.quit()
  })

  it('validates something', async () => {
    // write your test in here
  })
})
```

Go [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/start-testing-your-nativescript-apps-properly) for some great documentation